# Breaking up a print statement Python with intermediate process

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

When i run the script below, the print statement(s) appear at the same time. I would like the first print statement to display, then the loop to execute, then the run time to print.

Is there an additional statement I need to include?

```
import time
def main():
    Time = time.clock()
    print("Counting to 100,000,000:", end = "")

    for i in range(1,100000000):
        a = 3

    print(" -- Time: ", time.clock() - Time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the `flush` argument?

Answer (score 0):

There is a buffer in Python's standard output. This means that data you want to write (as in `print()`) is sometimes stored and then written in one go - as you are experiencing here.

To override this, just call `sys.stdout.flush()` which "flushes" everything already in this buffer out.

So to apply this to your code, it would look something like:

```
import time, sys
def main():
    Time = time.clock()
    print("Counting to 100,000,000:", end = "")
    sys.stdout.flush()

    for i in range(1,100000000):
        a = 3

    print(" -- Time: ", time.clock() - Time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which ran as expected for me (producing the following output) with the second part coming through later.

```
Counting to 100,000,000: -- Time:  4.796258999999999
```

Comment: `print()` has a `flush` argument, so you don't need to do it as an explicit step.